# Is it possible to see output to stdout after disown and logout?

Tags: linux, bash

I have done this to that programe:
ctrl-z
disown -h %1
bg 1

then logout,

Is it still possible for me to see what that programe outputs to stdout now?

Comment: You should consider running your programs inside GNU screen, and just detaching the screen session, if you want to be able to see their output or interact with them in the future.

Comment: 0) get screen http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/
1) run screen, you'll get a terminal window in screen
1) run your process,
2) detach screen (ctr+a d)
3) log off
4) log in again
5) reattach screen
6) screeen -r

Answer (score 3):

```
ctrl-z the program
bg %  so it wont die when you logoff
screen retty $Pid
will attach the running program into screen
```

duplicate question of [how to replace the "disown" with "screen"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006885)

Comment: Note: retty(1) is currently ia32 only (i.e. not 64bit).

Answer (score 2):

General [`screen` usage](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/screen/screen_toc.html):

```
user@machine:/home/user$ screen bash -l
user@machine:/home/user$ long_running_program
<user presses ctrl-a d to detach from the screen session>
user@machine:/home/user$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        58356.ttys000.machine     (Detached)
1 Socket in /tmp/uscreens/S-user.
user@machine:/home/user$ screen -r 58356
<user is connected to the original screen session>
```

Comment: Screen is a way to go.. Or nohup

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will help you, but you could call "gdb" and change the file descriptor.
See http://blog.tridgell.net/?p=4

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible..

Yes, this is an old question, but I'm sure others have been in the same position. This gentleman's gdb script wizardry allows one to "repoint" file descriptors in running processes. It can be done per-process by PID, or will call fuser to find all processes using the file. I also just confirmed it works on /dev/pty/*, so STD(IN,OUT,ERR) are possible as well.

http://groups.google.com/group/alt.hackers/browse_thread/thread/d1932c31ce43bd4c

.

Same as the answer I posted here: 
[how to replace the "disown" with "screen"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006885/how-to-replace-the-disown-with-screen/3654324#3654324)

Answer (score 0):

Not if you've logged out. The process will be writing stdout to the pty that was allocated on login, and logging out will remove this allocation. You'll have to redirect the stdout to a file, and then tail that.

Comment: I have the root priviledge,will it help?

Comment: It's not a privilege issue. It's an issue of streams being closed off upon logout