# how to replace the "disown" with "screen"?

Tags: bash

```
ctrl-z
disown -h %1
bg 1

logout
```

Comment: What is that code suppose to mean?

Comment: I assume he wants to detach a process from the current shell, and attach it to a screen session. +1 because I'm interested too.

Comment: Interesting, yes. But belongs on serverfault nonetheless :)

Comment: Yes. I would vote to close if I could.

Comment: It's related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006745/is-it-possible-to-see-output-to-stdout-after-disown-and-logout

Answer (score 4):

```
ctrl-z the program
bg %  so it wont die when you logoff
screen retty $Pid
will attach the running program into screen
```

Comment: please a detailed example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an old question, but I'm sure others have been in the same position.  This gentleman's gdb script wizardry allows one to "repoint" file descriptors in running processes.  It can be done per-process by PID, or will call fuser to find all processes using the file.  I also just confirmed it works on /dev/pty/*, so STD(IN,OUT,ERR) are possible as well.

http://groups.google.com/group/alt.hackers/browse_thread/thread/d1932c31ce43bd4c

Answer (score -1):

The one and only canonical way is to already start the stuff inside a screen.